# Load Athena output into Athena table

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

I used Athena to query a table, and got the output file as CSV that looks like this:

```
"col_a_string","col_b_string","col_c_timestamp","col_d_int"
```

Now, I want to take the csv file and load it into another Athena table so I can check my data and use it - but when I define my table with `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`, the values keep the parenthesis and all fields are considered string (what gives me blank columns for the timestamp and int columns).

It's a bit absurd that Athena can't read Athena output...
How can I define my table so it can ignore the parenthesis?

Thank you!

Comment: i think you are looking for  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-query-results/

Comment: Agreed that it is absurd, consider also that you cannot apply compression to Athena output from Athena.  You'll need to use something like Lambda or Glue to make that happen

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a feature now:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html

> A CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS) query creates a new table in Athena
>   from the results of a SELECT statement from another query. Athena
>   stores data files created by the CTAS statement in a specified
>   location in Amazon S3. For syntax, see CREATE TABLE AS.
>
> Use CTAS queries to:
>
> Create tables from query results in one step, without repeatedly
>   querying raw data sets. This makes it easier to work with raw data
>   sets.
>
> Transform query results into other storage formats, such as Parquet
>   and ORC. This improves query performance and reduces query costs in
>   Athena. For information, see Columnar Storage Formats.
>
> Create copies of existing tables that contain only the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
  `col_a_string` String,
  `col_b_string` String,
  `col_c_timestamp` TIMESTAMP, 
  `col_d_int ` Int,       
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
) LOCATION 's3://your-s3-location'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
```

Does this work for you? Note the `quotechar` attribute in the serialization / deserialization properties.

Comment: With openCSVSerde all column types in the create table statement need to be listed as strings.  From docs: When you use Athena with OpenCSVSerde, the SerDe converts all column types to STRING. Next, the parser in Athena parses the values from STRING into actual types based on what it finds. For example, it parses the values into BOOLEAN, BIGINT, INT, and DOUBLE data types when it can discern them. If the values are in TIMESTAMP in the UNIX format, Athena parses them as TIMESTAMP. If the values are in TIMESTAMP in Hive format, Athena parses them as INT. DATE type values are also parsed as INT.

Comment: To further convert columns to the desired type in a table, you can create a view over the table and use CAST to convert to the desired type.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually load data from csv.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table(
 `col_a_string` String,
 `col_b_string` String,
 `col_c_timestamp` TIMESTAMP, 
 `col_d_int ` Int)  
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
 'separatorChar' = ',', 
 'quoteChar' = '\"', 
 'escapeChar' = '\\' )
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '<s3://filepath>'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false',
          "skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Benefit of this is even if some columns are having double quotes, it will parse and load properly

eg.
col_a_string,"col_b_string",col_c_timestamp,"col_d_int"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked on me

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_table`(
  col_a_string` String,
 `col_b_string` String,
 `col_c_timestamp` TIMESTAMP, 
 `col_d_int ` Int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'escapeChar'='\\', 
  'separatorChar'=',') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://<path>'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'skip.header.line.count'='1')
```